# Error importing a file to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to import a tab separated values file into a PostgreSQL database using the "COPY" command. The problem is that is fails on a line with the error message

```
ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00
```

The bad line can be found in [this file](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~eldawy/bad_lines2).

It still fails when I try to import this single-line file.

I tried to open the file but it looks like a normal text file and I cannot find anyway to resolve this problem. The schema of the table looks like

```
CREATE TABLE osm_nodes (
  id BIGINT,
  longitude double precision,
  latitude double precision,
  tags TEXT
);
```

I use the following command to copy the file

cat bad_lines2 | psql  -c "COPY osm_nodes FROM STDIN WITH DELIMITER '   '"

(Note: The delimeter above is the tab character)

I use (PostgreSQL) 9.2.3.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. The text contains "\09" which was translated as a tab character and caused this problem. Each "\" should be escaped by "\" so that it can be inserted correctly.